# Getting a property of objects in an array, as an array, using Formik's useField hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, formik

Given a Formik context containing an array of objects:

```
{
  myArrayOfObjects: {
    property: string
  }[]
}
```

I would like to get an array of the values of `property`. I don't, however, have any idea whether this is possible. For further reference, I initially attempted `myArrayOfObjects.property` and `myArrayOfObjects[].property` in the hopes it would magically work, but unfortunately it does not.

The end goal here is to use this in tandem with a react-select multiselect field.

**Is this possible, and if not, what would be the proper way to work this out properly?**

This is on formik v2.2.6

Answer (score 0):

You can transform the data to get the array. There are possible better ways to do it, but this is the idea:

```js
const getPropertyValues = (values: InnerObject[]) => {
  const newArray: string[] = [];
  values.map((x: InnerObject) => {
    newArray.push(x.properties);
  });
  return newArray;
};
```

I did a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-hooks-kf2ld6?file=/src/App.tsx) so you can try it. I use that same function in 2 places:

1. To print the `values` of the form as an `string[]`
2. In the `SelectComponent` to create the options that will be displayed on the `react-select` component